# How to echo a php row with a link into a iframe src

Tags: php, html

Hey there I keep getting 404 errors when attempting to echo a link like this:

```
echo  '<iframe src="<?php echo $row["link"]; ?>"></iframe>';
```

Can anyone help?

what i receive as output in html is:

> ">

and 404 errors

Comment: You can't have PHP open/close tags in a PHP string. You're already in a PHP block. Change it to: `echo  '<iframe src="' . $row["link"] . '"></iframe>';`. [Here's the manual about string operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, do you mean switch them around like so?

> echo  "<iframe src='<?php echo $row["link"]; ?>'></iframe>";

Comment: use Magnus' comment. I've deleted mine, as it only pointed out 1 of 3 problems.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help that worked perfectly, and sorry for my ignorance

Comment: @CiaranBeatty - No need to be sorry. We've all started from scratch at some point. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
echo  '<iframe src="' . $row["link"] .'"></iframe>';
```

below one will not do something meaningful which is roughly equivalent what you've written.

```
echo "<?php /* some php code here */ ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Only double qoutes "" embeds the variable in to the string. Also you cant echo inside an echo

So change it to this

```
echo "<iframe src='{$row["link"]}'></iframe>";
```

or

```
echo '<iframe src="'.$row["link"].'"></iframe>';
```